# Wordcounting program in C

Tags: c

So I am trying to write a program that counts the number of words in a text file.

```
main(void){
    int wordcount = 0;
    FILE *infile = fopen("Text.txt", "r");
    wordcount += word_count(infile);
    printf("%d", wordcount);
    return 0;

    }

int word_count()
{
    int wordcount(FILE *infile);
    int count;
    char it;
    while ((it  = fgets(infile)!=EOF))
    {
        if (it =='\n')
        {
            count++
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

But when I run it, I got these errors:

```
infile undeclared identifier
fgets too few aruguments for function call
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `fgets` takes three arguments

Comment: okay! thanks! how would i be able to fix it?

Comment: 1.`word_count` function not taking any argument. use `word_count(FILE *infile) {`
2. `fgets` takes 3 args. read man `fgets`

Comment: Inside main function, you passing argument to `word_count(infile)` but while defining that function no argument is passed. why?

Comment: When you post questions that need help with resolving very simple compiler errors, there is very little motivation to provide positive feedback. Please grab a text book and take some time to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

First up, the segment:

```
int word_count()
{
    int wordcount(FILE *infile);
```

should be:

```
int word_count(FILE *infile) {
```

Secondly, `fgets()` takes *three* arguments, the buffer address, maximum size and file handle.

Third, if `fgets()` gets something, it returns a pointer to the buffer, not a character. If you're wanting to handle characters, you should be looking into `fgetc` instead.

Fourth, detecting the `\n` character is a good way to count *lines* but wot words. And you'd probably want to detect a final line without a newline on it as another line anyway (depending on your needs).

If you want to count words, you need to detect transitions between words and non-words.

Fifth, you should either move the word counting function to above `main` or provide a prototype for it above `main`. As it is now, it's not declared so you don't have type safety.

And, finally, `main()` should be declared to return an `int`.